# Can not build a subgraph: indentation error

Tags: graphql, blockchain, thegraph

I am trying to create a subgraph with the `graph-cli` and publish it to the Graph network. Here is my subgraph yaml file:

```
specVersion: 0.0.4
schema:
  file: ./schema.graphql
dataSources:
  – kind: ethereum
    name: Contract
    network: mainnet
    source:
      address: “0xc944e90c64b2c07662a292be6244bdf05cda44a7”
      abi: Contract
      startBlock: 11446769
    mapping:
      kind: ethereum/events
      apiVersion: 0.0.5
      language: wasm/assemblyscript
      entities:
        – Transfer
      abis:
        – name: Contract
          file: ./abis/Contract.json
      eventHandlers:
        – event: Transfer(indexed address,indexed address,uint256)
          handler: handleTransfer
      file: ./src/contract.ts
```

But when I am trying to build the subgraph with the `npm run codegen` command I am getting the following error:

[image]

But I am not sure how there is an indentation problem. How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong dash. You should do `-` rather than `–`.